# Macbook pro M1 command not found after oh my zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I have anaconda installed in my computer and after installing Oh my zsh. Conda and python etc. command is not found.

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

How can I fix this? It seems that the solutions I can find on the internet is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you installed it. You'll need to check your `PATH` variable, and compare against what you had in the original .zshrc file. You can then add it back like so

```
PATH="<PATH_TO_DIR_CONTAINING_CONDA:$PATH"
```

Comment: I just used the install method on ohmyzsh website. But the one you suggest is only for anaconda? so does this mean I have to do it manually for all the programs?

Comment: Oh nevermind. I have found a solution. Just paste whatever in the .zshrc file before ohmyzsh into it after installing. Thank you anyway